# "ENUM" is not vallid at his position, expecting ')'

Tags: mysql, syntax, enum

I'm keeping this error and I'm very new to mySQL so I don't know what is going on. The only way I found to remove this error  message is to put ')' before the ENUM and then the message change - "ENUM" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'.

```
USE labo3_partie2;
CREATE TABLE fournisseur(
        numero SMALLINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
        nom VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        prenom VARCHAR(40),
        chiffreAffaire DECIMAL(7,2) CHECK ((chiffreAffaire >= 20000) && (chiffreAffaire <= 1000000)),
        province CHAR(2) DEFAULT 'QC' ENUM('QC','ON','NB')
);
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL (and SQL in general??) is very picky about the order of things<sup>1</sup>.

```
province CHAR(2) DEFAULT 'QC' ENUM('QC','ON','NB')
```

-->

```
province  ENUM('QC','ON','NB')  DEFAULT 'QC'  -- if you want ENUM
```

But also, `ENUM` and `CHAR` are two different datatypes.  So, maybe you wanted this:

```
province CHAR(2) DEFAULT 'QC'                 -- if you want CHAR
```

---

1 - You should try to become comfortable reading syntax diagrams, [such as this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) for the `create table` statement.